# Как перепозиционировать элементы не меняя структуры html?

Tags: html, css, css3, позиционирование

Есть совместный блок с ценой стандартной и скидочной. Хочу поменять последовательность вывода стандартная цена, затем скидочная, причем оба блока должны выводиться по центру и цена будет каждый раз разная (а значит и ширина блоков будет каждый раз разная). Как это можно сделать с помощью стилей не меняя структуры `html` ? [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/y837g3gn/)

```css
del {
  float: right;
}
.price {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="price"><del><span class="amount">11.390&nbsp;<ruble title="руб.">руб.</ruble></span></del>  <ins><span class="amount">9.340&nbsp;<ruble title="руб.">руб.</ruble></span></ins>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть еще такой вариант

```
.price {
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}
del {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
ins {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/y837g3gn/4/

Comment: о вот так - супер! мне нравится. единственное, нужно поставить по 51% для отступов и для `price` назначить `min-height`

Answer (score 4):

Вот как можно перепозиционировать элементы:

```
.price{
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: к сожалению, `flex` сегодня еще не кроссбраузерный.. и при таком подходе элементы будут не по центру

Comment: На самом деле самый лучший ответ из всех представленных.

Comment: @Василий Барбашев я уже написал, почему он не подходит.. мне нужно кроссбраузерное решение и выравнивание по центру

Comment: @Вася Да, но понятие кроссбраузерности уже устарела. Это как использовать XP по сей день, имея на руках как минимум Win7:) Шутки шутками, но это наиболее современный и чистый подход.

Comment: @Вася эм? насколько кроссбраузерное? Он поддерживается абсолютно всеми современными браузерами + IE10-11. А для центровки есть ещё одно свойство

Comment: @Вася https://jsfiddle.net/do30p7ac/ пожалуйста, отцентрировал. Использование flex, является самым лучшим средством для верстки. Просто мало кто на нем что то умеет делать.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев опередил) лови +) Включил в ответ.

Comment: @Василий Барбашев возможно лучшее, но не сегодня пока живы `ie`. полноценная поддержка только в `edge` @Urmuz Tagizade про кроссбраузерность - не будем разводить холивар. в задачу любой грамотной студии входит кроссбраузерная верстка. если мы учимся, чтобы быть профессионалами, то она нам нужна иначе найдутся те, кто пристыдят

Answer (score 2):

```css
.price {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
}
del {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(5%);
}
ins {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-105%);
}
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <del>
    <span class="amount">11.390&nbsp;  <ruble title="руб.">руб.</ruble>
    </span>
  </del>
  <ins>
    <span class="amount">9.340&nbsp;  <ruble title="руб.">руб.</ruble>
    </span>
  </ins>
</div>
```

Comment: да, супер! только поставьте 110% для отступа и нужно `min-height` `price` назначить, чтобы блок не схлопнулся и не наехал

Comment: @Вася для добавления расстояния между ними отступы изменил на 5% и 105% - так ровнее будет относительно центра. а `min-height` то я добавил, но это уже другая история, не по теме)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38371/discussion-between-lexxl-and-).

Answer (score 2):

Если рядом нету других инлайновых элементов, то может такой подход сможет помочь?
[jsfiddle.net/y837g3gn/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/y837g3gn/2/)

```
<div class="price"><del><span class="amount">11.390&nbsp;<ruble title="руб.">руб.</ruble></span></del> <ins><span class="amount">9.340&nbsp;<ruble title="руб.">руб.</ruble></span></ins></div>

del {
  float:left;
  margin-left: -50%;
}
.price {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

Если есть, то после обеда можно поколдовать еще.

Comment: первой должна идти цена со скидкой

Comment: @Вася дак поменяй у `del` - `float: left` на `float: right`

Comment: @Василий Барбашев лучше, но цена смещена от центра

Comment: @Олег Дёгтев да, давайте еще поколдуем - решение где-то уже близко

Comment: Skywave придумал интересное решение. Там есть лишние строки, но идея хороша. Воспользуйтесь.

Comment: @Олег Дёгтев так и сделал, чуть подправив)